# Why is vim re-inserting my previous insert when I try to save?

Tags: vim, vi

I press `i` to start insert mode, type 'abc', then press `ESC` to leave insert. Then I press `i` to enter insert mode a second time, type 'def', and press `ESC` to leave insert, then type `:w` to save my work. When I look at what I've just typed, I expect to see 'abdefc'. However, what I actually see is 'abdefabcc'.

It seems that typing `:w` too quickly after hitting `ESC` causes vim to append whatever my previous insert was. Why is it doing this? How can I stop it?

Comment: How quick you execute `:w` once you hit escape? I am not able to reproduce this issue. **Note:** I have a typing speed of 89 words/min

Comment: Does this still happen with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: This seems to be related to ESC being used as part of specific sequences when in insert mode. The solution I have found is "don't use ESC", but that is not really satisfactory. I would prefer to remove the ESC delay, but I can't find where the insert-mode keybindings are specified.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, it does.